# Episerver Output Cache - implementing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, outputcache, episerver

I am trying to follow some instructions I found online in order to implement output caching for episerver.

In my web.config I have set up the following:

```
   <caching>
      <outputCache enableOutputCache="true">
      </outputCache>
      <outputCacheSettings>
        <outputCacheProfiles>
          <add name="ClientResourceCache" enabled="true" duration="3600" varyByParam="*" varyByContentEncoding="gzip;deflate" />
        </outputCacheProfiles>
      </outputCacheSettings>
    </caching>
```

As a test, I selected StartPageController.cs and added the `[ContentOutputCache]` tag like so:

```
    [ContentOutputCache]
    public class StartPageController : PageControllerBase<StartPage>
    {
        public ActionResult Index(StartPage currentPage)
        {
            var model = PageViewModel.Create(currentPage);

            if (SiteDefinition.Current.StartPage.CompareToIgnoreWorkID(currentPage.ContentLink)) 
            {

                var editHints = ViewData.GetEditHints<PageViewModel<StartPage>, StartPage>();
                editHints.AddConnection(m => m.Layout.Logotype, p => p.SiteLogotype);
                editHints.AddConnection(m => m.Layout.Footer, p => p.FooterBlock);
            }

            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

Then the instructions say:

> At some point on a page load you need to add the following code:
>
> public void SetResposneHeaders()
>           {
>               HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2.0));
>               HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
>               HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(true);
>           }

Due to my limited knowledge of .NET, MVC etc.. this part confuses me as I am not sure in which file to place it and where? Does this go in StartPageController.cs? Or somewhere else?

Any pointers would be appreciated.

The instructions I am trying to follow are [here](http://jondjones.com/learn-episerver-cms/episerver-developers-guide/episerver-caching/episerver-caching-the-output-cache-explained).

Comment: That last part shouldn't be necessary. Have you checked if it works without it? Note that you shouldn't be logged in, as the output cache will be disabled for logged-in users. Also, check the cache settings attributes of the `<applicationSettings>` element in web.config.

Comment: As far as I can tell it is not working. When I check the headers in the browser then cache-control is set to private. Here is the entry from web.config: <applicationSettings httpCacheability="Public" pageValidateTemplate="false" uiShowGlobalizationUserInterface="true" uiUrl="~/EPiServer/CMS/" urlRebaseKind="ToRootRelative" uiEditorCssPaths="~/Static/css/Editor.css" uiSafeHtmlTags="b,i,u,br,em,strong,p,a,img,ol,ul,li" />

Comment: not answering your question specifically, but - output cache and browser cache are different things; output cache means server will not render it again (i.e. create controller, load page data etc); browser cache means that browser (for example) will not request server at all until cache expires. That are different things used for different purposes, you need to carefully consider what you want. Say, output cache in episerver guarantees that if a page has been changed, then user will see updates; with browser cache, that is not true.